# Getting path from domain and redirecting to a URL

Tags: javascript, html, subdomain

I’m trying to create a sense of “dynamic” redirect, in which someone could visit the URL “repo.domain.tld/1” and it would redirect them to “site.tld/1”

I’ve tried using window functions in HTML but because of the hoster I’m using (surge.sh) it returns a 404.

Is there a way to do this in native HTML/JS?

Thank you!

Comment: Something like `document.location.href = "http://site.tld" + document.location.pathname`?

Comment: @helb yeah, but when I input the domain.tld/1 it gives a 404. should I just ignore this?

Comment: Well, that depends on the contents hosted at that domain. That `location.pathname` is just the part of address after TLD (eg. `"/questions/46921848/getting-path-from-domain-and-redirecting-to-a-url"` on this page).

Comment: I took at peek at surge.sh docs and they seem to have a better way to do redirects, kinda like with "oldschool" webservers: https://surge.sh/help/adding-redirects :)

Comment: @helb close to what I wanted, but I need something like dynamic. I’m trying to create a system where if someone goes to site.tld/myrepo it goes to github.com/mygit/myrepo without hard coding it

Comment: They have some dynamic url parts in the examples, something like `301   /:repo   https://github.com/you/:repo` should work.

Comment: @helb Just tried that, looks like you have to upgrade to the “Pro” plan to have ROUTER redirects. any other ideas?

Comment: Ah, okay. So the original plan with `document.location.href = "https://github.com/you" + document.location.pathname` should work (but you need a way to run the script on all urls you want to redirect, foo.tld/repo1, foo.tld/repo2 etc.). I usually do things like this with nginx, but i guess that's out of question with surge.sh hosting… This seems to be a way to do it there: https://surge.sh/help/adding-a-200-page-for-client-side-routing

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you used. But this should work.

```
window.location = "https://www.example.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use surge's [`200.html`](https://surge.sh/help/adding-a-200-page-for-client-side-routing) page for client side routing (to avoid 404s) with a simple script:

```
<script>
    var githubName = "user";
    document.location.href = "https://github.com/" + githubName + document.location.pathname;
    // for domain.tld/repo1 it would go to github.com/user/repo1 
</script>
```